# Parsing and summarizing an aviation METAR (US) report

Tags: java, parsing

I have a list of objects, which contains field `rawData` (eg rawData="KLAX 141353Z 06003KT 6SM BR FEW002 FEW008 BKN280 12/12 A3007 RMK AO2 SLP182 T01170117 $"). In my case rawData is METAR report from which i want to extract the most severe weather condition (clouds, fog, rain, snow).
Currently I am applying `parseWeather` to each object of my list.

METAR string can contain multiple instance of same tag e.g. (BRN065 BRN033),  it even can contain all of them in same time . To my output - I want to display "simplified" worst weather condition, where the worst, for the current task, is considered as fog, then snow, then other weather conditions.

To answer why i return same type as argument - initial argument have some pre parsed detailed report from FlightAware service. However I have different requirenment for simplified report, than provided. Thus function `parseWeather` is a side effect function which fills extra fields.

```
  private PollFlightResponse.ResultEntity.MetarEntity parseWeather(
      PollFlightResponse.ResultEntity.MetarEntity d) {

    int severity = 0; //how bad is weather from 0 to 2
    String wCode = ""; // map key
    String weather = ""; // human readable weather
    if (d.getRawData().contains("FG")) {
      wCode = "FG";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("+SN")) {
      wCode = "+SN";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("SN")) {
      wCode = "SN";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("-SN")) {
      wCode = "-SN";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("+RA")) {
      wCode = "+RA";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("-RA")) {
      wCode = "-RA";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("RA")) {
      wCode = "RA";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("VV")) {
      wCode = "VV";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("OVC")) {
      wCode = "OVC";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("BKN")) {
      wCode = "BKN";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("SCT")) {
      wCode = "SCT";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("FEW")) {
      wCode = "FEW";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("NSC")) {
      wCode = "NSC";
    } else if (d.getRawData().contains("CLR")) {
      wCode = "CLR";
    } 

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(wCode)) {
      wCode = "CLR";
    }
    weather = SearchActivity.conditions.get(wCode);
    severity = SearchActivity.severity.get(wCode);
    if (d.getRawData().contains("MPS")) {
      int index = d.getRawData().indexOf("MPS");
      String wind = d.getRawData().substring(index - 2, index);
      int s = Integer.parseInt(wind);
      if (s == 0) {
        //no wind does not affect results
      } else if (s < 3) {
        weather += ", Light wind";
      } else if (s < 10) {
        weather += ", Windy";
        if (severity < 1) severity = 1;
      } else {
        weather += ", Strong wind";
        if (severity < 1) severity = 2;
      }
    }
    d.setGeneraWeather(weather);
    d.setWeatherSeverity(severity);
    return d;
  }
```

where conditions and severity is static public hashmaps

```
  private void generateWeatherMap() {
    conditions.clear();
    severity.clear();

    //Strings
    conditions.put("FG", "Fog");
    conditions.put("+SN", "Heavy snow");
    conditions.put("SN", "Snow");
    conditions.put("-SN", "Light snow");
    conditions.put("+RA", "Heavy rain");
    conditions.put("RA", "Rain");
    conditions.put("-RA", "Light rain");
    conditions.put("CLR", "Clear sky");
    conditions.put("NSC", "Little clouds");
    conditions.put("FEW", "Few clouds");
    conditions.put("SCT", "Scattered clouds");
    conditions.put("BKN", "Broken clouds");
    conditions.put("OVC", "Overcast");
    conditions.put("VV", "Heavy precipitation");
    //Values
    severity.put("FG", 2);
    severity.put("+SN", 2);
    severity.put("SN", 1);
    severity.put("-SN", 1);
    severity.put("+RA", 1);
    severity.put("RA", 1);
    severity.put("-RA", 1);
    severity.put("CLR", 0);
    severity.put("NSC", 0);
    severity.put("FEW", 0);
    severity.put("SCT", 1);
    severity.put("BKN", 1);
    severity.put("OVC", 2);
    severity.put("VV", 2);
  }
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Peilonrayz thank you, I reverted edited code part

Comment: You should write unit tests until you reach 100% code coverage. Doing that you will notice that your code is buggy since it never reports `"SN-"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself calling the same immutable method dozens of times, you should think about storing the result in a local variable. I count 17 calls to `d.getRawData()`, which I assume all give the same result. (If not, you have other problems!)

---

You're using an object-oriented language, so take advantage of its features. An existing answer has pointed out that the if-else chain could be simplified to a loop, but it doesn't go far enough. If you define a class

```
class WeatherCondition {
    WeatherCondition(string code, string condition, int severity) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

then you can replace the `conditions` and `severity` maps with a single `List<WeatherCondition>` in priority order and replace the first 41 lines of the first code block with

```
  private PollFlightResponse.ResultEntity.MetarEntity parseWeather(
      PollFlightResponse.ResultEntity.MetarEntity d) {

      // Fallback value
      WeatherCondition weather = new WeatherCondition("CLR", "Clear sky", 0);
      String rawData = d.getRawData();
      for (WeatherCondition condition : conditions) {
          if (condition.matches(rawData)) {
              weather = condition;
              break;
          }
      }
```

(I'm not up to date on streams: there may be more idiomatic ways to do this in Java 8).

Note that this relies on a method `WeatherCondition.matches(String)`. Your code effectively implements this as

```
rawData.contains(code)
```

but **that is buggy**: it matches `SN` in any report containing `-SN` or `+SN`. An improved hack would be

```
rawData.contains(" " + code)
```

but since this is supposed to be a parser it should really **use the grammar** and not just random substrings which could appear in other contexts. (That's **another bug** with the original code: `FG` is a substring of airport codes in Equatorial Guinea, among others, so it would claim that it's always foggy there).

---

Here's one thing I don't understand because there isn't enough context given: why on Earth is the return type of `parseWeather` the same as the argument type? If you have the parsed instance already, can't you just return it? If not, shouldn't the argument just be the `String`?

---

And one final note: based on my quick background reading to answer this, I think that this method is specific to US METAR rather than the international standard. If that's the case, it should be clearly documented.

Comment: Thank you for extended review. I answered aboud method return type in question body

Answer (score 1):

**A question before**

It is not clear to me how yor code works, but could as I'm not an expert of this *METAR* format.

The weather you find is just the last you get from the input string.

If you have, for example, an *Heavy show* you will miss it as you could even have a *Overcast*.

This part is much a question, than an answer, sorry.

Assuming your code is correct and the input string contains only one weather condition, here are my considerations.

**Advise 1**

You should use a for loop with the *keys* of *SearchActivity.conditions*, and break as soon as you find the conditions, avoiding matching all others.

So for example:

```
String weather = SearchActivity.conditions.get("CLR");

for (String condition : SearchActivity.conditions.keySet()) {
   if (d.getRawData().contains(condition)) {
       weather = SearchActivity.conditions.get(condition);
       break;
   }
}
```

Of course if you really need the last match, than you could not use this loop, as the *Set* don't preserve the order of the keys.

In this case, if you still want to have a loop, you should create an array with the conditions keys.

**Advise 2**

You should use constant for the condition labels:

```
final String CLR = "CLR";
final String FOG = "Fog";
... so on...
```

And use those constants in your code.

**EDIT**

For example in your *if else*:

```
if (d.getRawData().contains(FOG)) {
    wCode = FOG;
} else if (...
} else {
    wCode = CLR;
}
```

**A review on the code**

Your *if else* statement is not correct, as the last check could be just an *else*:

```
....
} else if (d.getRawData().contains("NSC")) {
  wCode = "NSC";
} else {
  wCode = "CLR";
}
```

As after you check if the *wCode* variable is empty and the you force *CLR*, that is the last condition.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(wCode)) {
  wCode = "CLR";
}
```

Comment: Sorry for missleading, I added Edit to my post to describe more expected input  and output. About advise 2, do you mean to use those variables to remove wCode variable, e.g. `else if (d.getRawData().contains("SN")) {
      weather = Weather.SN;} `, where SN is a final String with value `snow`? Thanks for pointing to reduntunt `TextUtils.isEmpty(wCode)` check

Comment: @Yarh I updated the post. About avoid the *wCode* if you stay with the *if else* it lead to duplicate the map access. The important stap is to use constant istead of raw strings in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should get rid of this if-else chain. You look for the first occurence of a string X out of a known list and then assign that X to a variable. So do this in a loop:

```
 String[] definitions = { "FG", "+SN", "SN", "-SN", "+RA", "-RA", "RA", "VV", "OVC", "BKN", "SCT", "FEW", "NSC", "CLR" };
 String wCode = "CLR"; // fallback if nothing matches
 for(String def : definitions) {
      if(d.getRawData().contains(def)) {
           wCode = def;
           break;
      }
 }
```

(Or alternatives usings streams/filters/findFirst - the possibilities are numerous.)

Then, even if that has been refactored out in the first part of my answer (:-)) don't use whatever library to do basic functions from the standard library:

```
 TextUtils.isEmpty(wCode)
```

should be

```
 wCode.isEmpty()
```

instead (esp. as you can be sure that wCode != null as you did an initial assignment to the variable) - every java programmer understands that without looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the code and I would have used this approach:

```
private PollFlightResponse.ResultEntity.MetarEntity parseWeather(
  PollFlightResponse.ResultEntity.MetarEntity d) {

int severity = 0; //how bad is weather from 0 to 2
String wCode = ""; // map key
String weather = ""; // human readable weather
Enum urgentCodes{ FG("FG"), PSN("+SN), ......}
urgentCodes code = urgentCodes.valueOf(currentCodeRead);
 switch(code)
 {
      case FG:          conditions.put("FG", "Fog");
                        severity.put("FG", 2);
                        break;

       case
       .....
       default:         //Conditons are clear code
  }
```

In writing this, I would make this into an object where I would set the values to be static. I would then create a method where the call would look like:

```
while ( code != '$' and code.hasNext() == true) //Looked like the marker //for the end of the line
{
     int severity = weather.contitionLevel(String code);
     String weatherCond = weather.condition(String code);
}
```

Now of course `try` and `catch` statements will have to be added for IO errors.